# How to find current setting of "FORCE PARALLEL QUERY" in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c

I can change (override) the current level of parallelism in an Oracle session using e.g.:

```
alter session force parallel query parallel 6;
```

Is there any system view of function that will return me the value `6` that I have requested?

I would like to check (in a stored procedure) if my current session has changed this (ideally the setting for a `alter session force parallel dml` as well)

Comment: I think you're going to have to delve into a `x$` table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on 12.1 but should work if you have appropriate privileges in versions where this view and feature is available. you will see rows **only if** value is non-default. If query returns 0 rows, it means value is default. Please test and adjust view names for your environment.

```
Select name, value From Sys.V_$ses_Optimizer_Env 
Where Sid = (Select Distinct Sid From Sys.V_$mystat)
And Name In ('parallel_query_forced_dop','parallel_dml_forced_dop');
```

Comment: Works fine. The `select` from `v_$mystat` is not needed btw. `Where Sid = userenv ('SID')` is working just fine. I also used `v$ses_optimizer_env` instead of `Sys.V_$ses_Optimizer_Env`

Comment: as I mentioned feel free to tweak as needed, glad it worked out.  BTW if you read about parallel_query_forced_dop ,you will notice that it actually doesn't do much but it does influence optimizer calculations. Tanel has a nice article on it, slightly older article but useful http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2013/03/20/alter-session-force-parallel-query-doesnt-really-force-anything/